# Edit existing table in MySQL data base with JSON

Tags: php

There is a few JSON lines:

```
[{"id":"1","word_item":"house","word_translation":"translation1","word_language":"English","word_rank":"0"},

{"id":"26","word_item":"cat","word_translation":"translation2","word_language":"English","word_rank":"1"},

{"id":"27","word_item":"man","word_translation":"translation3","word_language":"English","word_rank":"2"},

{"id":"28","word_item":"Lorem","word_translation":"translation","word_language":"English","word_rank":"5"}]
```

First I get it from the server with word_rank = 0 for all the lines. After the user types in a special input the translation of the words from "word_item", js code compares the user's answer with corresponding "word_translation". Each error adds one point to the "word_rank", you can see it in the JSON above.

How can I update the table in my DB with php so that I could save new word ranks after the user answered the questoin? I mean, the user clicks the button, json changes, it is send to the server

Comment: Are each of these lines a record in your DB table?

Comment: Yes, there is a table with colomns id, word_item, word_translation, etc. Each part in the curly brackets is a line from this table

Answer (score 0):

If you have the most recent version of MySQL you can filter results with [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) and you can then update JSON with [JSON_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set).

Comment: @Ramzes, did this work for you? If so, please kindly accept the answer as the accepted answer. Thanks.